# The whole JSON Vs. rows and columns ( Database )

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a list of JSON that I encoded look something like this :

[image]

**Note** : Image is just part of it, not all.

After I decode it, it looks something like this :

[image]

**Note** : Image is just part of it, not all.

I want to add those data into my database and I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this. There are 2 ways that I thinking right now :

1. **Inserting the whole JSON into my database**

   - If I choose to to this way, will it's effect anything in term of complication or performance wise ? Is it bad ?
2. **Create a table in my database, that match the data in the JSON**

   - Loop through all them and insert each of them.
   - This one is a little more work, and I hope that it's better.

Anybody want to throw in some opinion on this ? Thanks.

Comment: `Inserting the whole JSON into my database,  Is it bad ?` Depends, will you ever want to sort, filter, or otherwise do something useful with this information other than just moving it around in a giant blob?

Comment: You can store JSON data in mysql database only as text in a single field. This would entirely defeat the purpose of storing data into RDBMS and would complicate queries.

Comment: @MLeFevre : I see what you mean. I kind of see the picture now. To answer to your question. I just want to store them somwhere, and be able to retrieve them when I need them. Nothing fancy here.

Comment: @Whirlwind : I see. What if I store the whole php array into my database ?  Will it still bad ?

Comment: It depends on how you plan to use your data, like @MLeFevre pointed. You can't perform sorting or search queries on the actual content in both ways.

Comment: @evoque2015 retrieve them _how_ though? If you want to be able to do something like `Get all rows where Approved = TRUE and Bin# = 5`, then store it properly, create a column for each field, index them accordingly and give them each a sensible type. If you currently don't, and never will, have a part in processing this information, and just need to store it somewhere, i wouldn't even worry about using a database, create a folder somewhere and throw them in there as separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where this data comes from. But it's obviously a JSON representation of an ordinary RDMS table. The first array element is a list of column names, and the subsequent ones are rows in those columns.  In some of those rows you have some missing columns.

Whoever cooked up this data format seemed to be influenced by RDMS (MySQL, etc) design.  You might be wise to store it in a table.  If you do you'll have SQL's power to access and report on it, for example,

```
SELECT COUNT(*), itemName, salesDescription
  FROM table
 WHERE isActive = 'Y'
 GROUP BY itemName, salesDescription
```

will summarize what kind of items you have and how many.

(You could get that power also from MongoDB, of course.)

This is a QuickBooks export, you said in a comment. QB uses an RDMS under the covers, so its data is table and row oriented, as this example shows. If this were my project, I'd export the CSV file from QB and then load it into a RDMS directly, without mucking around with JSON.

Comment: I got this JSON from a .csv file that I export from QuickBooks. This is just the sample one. According to your answer, do you suggest to store as a JSON or stay away from it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you are going to treat this data. How you are going to query it, and if you are going to edit the data. 
If you are going to query this data by its attributes you should maintain a table with matching columns.

I just realized that your JSON might be more useful if instead of saving a list of lists where the first list is holding names you would have one list of objects.

```
[{"id":1234,"name":"somename"},{"id":567,"name":"somothername"} ]
```

Comment: This data will not plan to Edit or anything like that. This data will be new everyday - so what is your thought now ?

Answer (score 1):

I think both approaches are valid depending on what you want to do with that data next.

If you are planning on using this data on the client side only (javascript), then storing the json in the DB would not be such a bad idea. You could store it in a column with type "text" and another column with an id to identify your different jsons somehow.

If, on the other hand, you are planning to process this data on the server side (php for example) I think it would be better to store it as a normal relational database (tables, columns and rows). By processing the data I mean for example: order it, grouping it, or retrieve only some part of the data, etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First option is ok if you just need to store the data in database. For example you won't be able to search for item that's called "Installation Repair"

Second way is much better if you want to perform some operations on these data (select, update etc.)